# A PHP Error was encountered array conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can you help how to solve this im new in Php codeigniter. this code that get error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: controllers/employers.php

Line Number: 44

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tedyaya/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:186)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 543

Comment: Can you pls show us your controller? employers.php. It states that there's an error in line 44

Comment: $config['upload_path'] = $path;
            $config['file_name'] = url_title(strtolower($this->input->post('Username'))) . $this->upload->data('file_ext');
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|';
            $config['max_size'] = '';
            $config['max_width'] = '';
            $config['max_height'] = '';
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $err = 'failed_reg';
            $ok = true;

Comment: $config['upload_path'] = $path;
            $config['file_name'] = url_title(strtolower($this->input->post('Username'))) . $this->upload->data('file_ext');
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|';
            $config['max_size'] = '';
            $config['max_width'] = '';
            $config['max_height'] = '';
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $err = 'failed_reg';
            $ok = true;

Comment: Edit your question

Comment: $config['upload_path'] = $path; $config['file_name'] = url_title(strtolower($this->input->post('Username'))) . $this->upload->data('file_ext'); $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|'; $config['max_size'] = ''; $config['max_width'] = ''; $config['max_height'] = ''; $this->upload->initialize($config); $err = 'failed_reg'; $ok = true;

Comment: That is the code that got error inline 44

Comment: @RichfieldTFlores It is a bit hard to see all that code in your comments I would recommend you to edit your question by clicking on the edit button below tags.

Comment: NO edit  button in the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error telling you that you are trying an array to convert in string..

For example

```
<?php
$a = array("Apple","Bnana");
echo $a;//Will give you same error 
?>
```

But

```
<?php
$a = array("Apple","Bnana");
print_r($a);//Will not give you any error
?>
```

Comment: $config['upload_path'] = $path;
            $config['file_name'] = url_title(strtolower($this->input->post('Username'))) . $this->upload->data('file_ext');
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|';
            $config['max_size'] = '';
            $config['max_width'] = '';
            $config['max_height'] = '';
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $err = 'failed_reg';
            $ok = true;

Answer (score 0):

Use print_r/var_dump in your controllers/employers.php line 44.

Comment: How sir im new in php codeigniter?

Comment: $config['upload_path'] = $path;
            $config['file_name'] = url_title(strtolower($this->input->post('Username'))) . $this->upload->data('file_ext');
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|';
            $config['max_size'] = '';
            $config['max_width'] = '';
            $config['max_height'] = '';
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $err = 'failed_reg';
            $ok = true;

Comment: my files is ruuning in my localhost? when i transfer in the server this errror appear in my submit button of my site

Comment: '$config['upload_path'] = $path;
            $config['file_name'] = url_title(strtolower($this->input->post('Username'))) . $this->upload->data('file_ext');
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|';
            $config['max_size'] = '';
            $config['max_width'] = '';
            $config['max_height'] = '';
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $err = 'failed_reg';
            $ok = true;'

Comment: `code`$config['upload_path'] = $path;
            $config['file_name'] = url_title(strtolower($this->input->post('Username'))) . $this->upload->data('file_ext');
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|';
            $config['max_size'] = '';
            $config['max_width'] = '';
            $config['max_height'] = '';
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $err = 'failed_reg';
            $ok = true;

Comment: `code`$config['upload_path'] = $path;
            $config['file_name'] = url_title(strtolower($this->input->post('Username'))) . $this->upload->data('file_ext');
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|';
            $config['max_size'] = '';
            $config['max_width'] = '';
            $config['max_height'] = '';
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $err = 'failed_reg';
            $ok = true;

Comment: `code`$config['upload_path'] = $path;
            $config['file_name'] = url_title(strtolower($this->input->post('Username'))) . $this->upload->data('file_ext');
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|';
            $config['max_size'] = '';
            $config['max_width'] = '';
            $config['max_height'] = '';
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $err = 'failed_reg';
            $ok = true;`code`

Comment: `code $config['upload_path'] = $path;
            $config['file_name'] = url_title(strtolower($this->input->post('Username'))) . $this->upload->data('file_ext');
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|';
            $config['max_size'] = '';
            $config['max_width'] = '';
            $config['max_height'] = '';
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $err = 'failed_reg';
            $ok = true;`